# CMake exclude tests in subdirectories

Tags: cmake, ctest

I have a c++ project which includes libevent library. Project structure:

```
.
|_ CMakeLists.txt
|_ Makefile
|_ src
| |_ my_lib.cpp
|_ test
| |_ my_lib_test.cpp
|_ lib
  |_ libevent
    |_ CMakeLists.txt
    |_ ...
```

When I build and run my tests, libevent tests are also executed. How can I exclude them and run only my own tests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [available `option`s](https://github.com/libevent/libevent/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L41) in libevent's CMakeLists.txt file, it appears that you can disable these pretty easily by setting `EVENT__DISABLE_TESTS` to `ON`.

You can either do this in your own CMakeLists.txt before libevent is included:

```
set(EVENT__DISABLE_TESTS ON)
...
add_subdirectory(lib/libevent)
```

or when you invoke CMake on the command line:

```
cmake . -DEVENT__DISABLE_TESTS=ON
```

Comment: What if it's not only libevent next time? Is there a standard CMake way to disable/enable subproject tests?

Comment: No.  You're just lucky in this case that the creators of the libevent CMakeLists.txt have made the effort to provide this option.  Lots of other projects do have similar options to avoid building tests/examples/docs/etc. but many do not.  For those that don't, you'd *have* to modify their CMakeLists.txt files (e.g. to remove/skip all instances of the [`add_test`] command).

Answer (score 9):

There is also a more general way to do it. Add a file named `CTestCustom.cmake` to your source tree and add a list of tests that you want `CTest` not to run:

```
set(CTEST_CUSTOM_TESTS_IGNORE
   test1
   ....
   testN
)
```

Then copy this file to the build directory where tests are executed:

```
configure_file(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CTestCustom.cmake ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
```

This will make `CTest` ignore the listed tests. See [this](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake/Testing_With_CTest) for more info.

Comment: That's not very convenient: I'd like to exclude testing 3rd party libraries, and it is a bit tiresome to enumerate hundreds of tests.

Answer (score 7):

I've found another (better) way to solve the actual question.

**TL;DR**

Add to your CMakeLists.txt file:

```
configure_file(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CTestCustom.cmake ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} @ONLY)
```

Add do your `CTestCustom.cmake` file in your source code:

```
file (STRINGS "@CMAKE_BINARY_DIR@/CTestTestfile.cmake" LINES)

# overwrite the file....
file(WRITE "@CMAKE_BINARY_DIR@/CTestTestfile.cmake" "")

# loop through the lines,
foreach(LINE IN LISTS LINES)
  # remove unwanted parts
  string(REGEX REPLACE ".*directory_to_remove.*" "" STRIPPED "${LINE}")
  # and write the (changed) line ...
  file(APPEND "@CMAKE_BINARY_DIR@/CTestTestfile.cmake" "${STRIPPED}\n")
endforeach()
```

(See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59506088/4166604 for a function form of removing a line)

**Explanation:**

The excluding per test method has many downsides, including dynamically (via a macro) added tests, wasted time, etc...

This was tested on CMake 3.x: When a CMake project with tests enabled is built, a `CTestTestfile.cmake` file is generate in the `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`. Essentially every time `add_subdirectory` is called, an equivalent `subdirs` command is added to the `CTestTestfile.cmake` file. The `CTestTestfile.cmake` files will mimic an equivalent directory structure as the `CMakeLists.txt` files. (So if you need to remove a sub directory in another directory, that's the `CTestTestfile.cmake` you need to edit).

The `CTestCustom.cmake` is executed before the `CTestTestfile.cmake`, so all `CTestCustom.cmake` needs to do is remove the offending line from the `CTestTestfile.cmake` file. This could be done with a `sed`, but in the spirit of cross compatibility, it's all pure CMake now. The `CTestCustom.cmake` does not have `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` set, so we use `@` substitution to get the value of `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` at CMake generate time, and replace the values that will be in the `CTestCustom.cmake` copy in the build directory, using `@ONLY` replacement, to leave the other variables `$` alone.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Ivan Baidakou.

I'm not sure this is much better, but here's a non-portable hack (won't work on Windows by default) to get it done.

```
execute_process(COMMAND sh -c "echo 'set(CTEST_CUSTOM_TESTS_IGNORE'; find '${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/relative_paths' -path '*tests/CMakeLists.txt' -exec sed -nE '/add_test.*NAME/{s|.*NAME *([^ ]+).*|\\1|; p}' {} +; echo ')'"
                OUTPUT_FILE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/CTestCustom.cmake)
```

Where `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/relative_paths` can be multiple paths for multiple libraries if you want.