# How to remove a line of text in a string in CMake, working around CMake's lack of line-based regex matching?

Tags: regex, cmake

I found out that CMake doesn't do RegEx the way I expected.  [Apparently, others have had this same problem as well.](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2007-October/017107.html) The issue is that CMake is not line-based.  When you use the `^` or the `$` operators, they work against the entire string, not the start and end of a line.

I'm trying to remove all the lines in a file that say `#include <blah.h>` or `#include "blah.h"`.

To do so, I whipped up a little function:

```
function(deleteinplace IN_FILE pattern)
    file(READ ${IN_FILE} CONTENTS)
    string(REGEX REPLACE ${pattern} "" STRIPPED ${CONTENTS})
    file(WRITE ${IN_FILE} "${STRIPPED}")
endfunction()
```

Then to call it:

`deleteinplace(myfile.h "\#include.*\n")`

This ends up removing everything in the file after the string is matched.

Non-Greedy tricks like `.*?` don't work in CMake for some reason.  Other tricks like `\r?\n` also do not work.

I need a work around for this.

Comment: Can you use something more specific like `#include [<"][^>"]+[>"]`?

Answer (score 5):

The trick is **not** to use `file(READ ...)`, but `file(STRINGS ....)`. This will let `CMake` read file line by line, and return a list of strings representing one line each, exactly as you need. Using this approach, your function would look like this:

```
function(deleteinplace IN_FILE pattern)
  # create list of lines form the contens of a file
  file (STRINGS ${IN_FILE} LINES)

  # overwrite the file....
  file(WRITE ${IN_FILE} "")
  
  # loop through the lines,
  # remove unwanted parts 
  # and write the (changed) line ...
  foreach(LINE IN LISTS LINES)
    string(REGEX REPLACE ${pattern} "" STRIPPED "${LINE}")
    file(APPEND ${IN_FILE} "${STRIPPED}\n")
  endforeach()
endfunction()
```

Then to call it:

```
deleteinplace(myfile.h "\#include.*")
```

Note that in this example `\n` is automatically stripped from the lines as a part of `file(STRINGS ....)` statement, and added back within `file(APPEND ....)` statement; therefore, `\n` was also removed from the search pattern when calling the function.

At the end, here is the documentation about [file(STRINGS ...)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/command/file.html#strings)